# Installing GNU mailutils on windows

Tags: windows, command-line, email, cygwin, gnu

I'm using Windows 7, and would like to use the GNU mailutils, specifically mu and mu4e. Unfortunately, these are not available as Cygwin packages. Is there any way to use GNU mailutils on windows *without* a virtual machine?

I spent an hour trying to compile from source under Cygwin and finally gave up because there were too many dependencies to install. I know the right thing to do is run linux in a VM or switch to linux entirely, but I thought I'd ask this first.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

All software requires a compatible environment in which to run. For the GNU mailutils that environment is Linux. Windows is not Linux.
Cygwin allows you to run in Windows Linux programs that have been compiled for it. The only other alternative would be to run them under a virtual machine.

The only other possibility would be to port GNU Mailutils to Windows. But I expect that would be more difficult than compiling them for Cygwin.